# Unsubscribe Firestore listener on logout

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

The straightforward way to do this is explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

However i am having a hard time trying to trigger the unsubscribe within a `onAuthStateChanged` which is in a different vuex module

store/user.js

```
...
  onAuthStateChanged({ commit, dispatch }, { authUser }) {
    if (!authUser) {
      commit('RESET_STORE')
      this.$router.push('/')
      return
    }
    commit('SET_AUTH_USER', { authUser })
    dispatch('database/getUserItems', null, { root: true })
    this.$router.push('/home')
  }
...
```

store/database.js

```
...
getUserItems({ state, commit }, payload) {
    const unsubscribe = this.$fireStore
      .collection('useritems')
      .where('owner', '==', this.state.user.authUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          // STUFF
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
  },
...
```

How do i reference `unsubscribe()` from the user.js module when the user logs out (authUser undefined)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just save it in you Vuex `state` tree and call it from there.

```
  state: {
    //....
    listenerUnsubscribe: null,
    //....
  },
  mutations: {
    //....
    SET_LISTENER_UNSUBSCRIBE(state, val) {
        state.listenerUnsubscribe = val;
    },
    RESET_STORE(state) {
        state.listenerUnsubscribe()
    }
    //....
  },
  actions: {
    //....
    getUserItems({ state, commit }, payload) {
        const unsubscribe = this.$fireStore
        .collection('useritems')
        .where('owner', '==', this.state.user.authUser.uid)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // STUFF
            },
            (error) => {
            console.log(error)
            }
        );
        commit('SET_LISTENER_UNSUBSCRIBE', unsubscribe);
    },
```

Comment: I've tried that already, unfortunately it always returns the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.listenerUnsubscribe is not a function`

Comment: I've just tried and it does work for me. Can you share your entire code in your question, including how you call that `RESET_STORE` mutation (please edit the questions and add your new code).

Comment: Ok I got it working. The only thing i changed was to call the unsubscribe() commit before  the fireauth.signout() call rather than in onAuthStateChanged(). Basically your approach of saving the function to vuex worked.